# Are Minecraft JE data packs considered mods?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/373137/minecraft-data-packs-do-not-work-on-my-server) is a question that asks for technical support of Minecraft JE Data Packs.

From the Minecraft Wiki:

> The data pack system provides a way for players to further customize their Minecraft experience. Data packs can be used to override or add new advancements, dimensions, functions, loot tables, predicates, recipes, structures, tags, world generation settings, and biomes‌[upcoming: JE 1.16.2] without any code modification.

Are technical support requests of Minecraft data packs on-topic?

### Arguments for **YES**

- It is not an item that changes the game's code, just the files.

### Arguments for **NO**

- It is considered a way of customizing your Minecraft experience, just like mods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm inclined to say that, in general, these sorts of questions should be on topic.  I would not close this particular question for the modded Minecraft reason.  There are a few parts to data packs that are definitely on topic here: function files (commands) and drop tables in particular.  Additionally, questions asking how to configure and use a data pack should be on topic.  That's essentially what this question is asking, just in a server setting.

Having said all that, I still think the linked question should be closed, but because it needs more details, not because it's "modded" Minecraft tech support.  An image showing the contents of the data packs directory is not at all sufficient.  I don't know the exact details about enabling data packs on a server, but having a look at the asker's server settings file would also be useful.